# Heroku rake db:migrate doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Ruby 1.9.2 Rails 3.1

After the day of fighting with heroku issues I was able to finally have the command 'git push heroku master to work properly'.

Gemfile has proper enties and pg gem is installed

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

At this point application has been uploaded and start page can be viewed here http://growing-day-7939.heroku.com/

The next step should be migrating the database to the heroku with 'heroku rake db:migrate"
and it always fails.

```
c:\RailsInstaller\work\rfclub>heroku rake db:migrate
No app specified.
Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app <app name>
```

Other heroku commands fail with the same error as above - heroku ps, heroku logs, heroku config.

I've tried deleting and recreating the app, even tried creating the new heroku account and repeating the steps, but nothing seems to help.
Any ideas would be appreciated, I'm really stuck.

Comment: @Ahmish I've updated the post with the message, I should have included it. See above. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll need to deploy Rails 3.1 apps on [Heroku's Cedar stack](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar), via `heroku create --stack cedar`. The migration command will be `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple heroku remotes for the same repo you need to specify one when running heroku commands: `heroku run rake db:migrate --app my_app2`

Comment: Wow.... heroku run rake db:migrate --app my_app2 - this one actually did the trick (without specifying the --app my_app2 it just refused to work)